# How would one define a subscription filter for a boolean value

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to create a subscription filter for a boolean attribute value.

I tried the following:

```
attributes.apiIntegration = "TRUE"
attributes.apiIntegration = "true"
attributes.apiIntegration = "1"
```

None of them seem to catch the messages I am looking to filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attributes in messages map string keys to string values, so there is no such thing as a boolean attribute. Therefore, the value in your attribute is a string that is getting translated from the boolean. How that translation occurs could depend on the language you are using and/or the library you are using to convert the boolean to a string. In order to know how to match it, you need to look at the attributes of your published message and see how the boolean is being converted to a string. It could be any of the three cases you mention, it could also be `"True"`. To be sure, look at the messages right before publishing them or pull them with a subscription that has no filter in order to see how the boolean value is being converted.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @kamal-aboul-hosn. We are using dotnet and turns out that the correct mapping for us is:

```
attributes.apiIntegration = "True"
```